# How to use Gnuplot addin for Excel

Tags: excel, plot, gnuplot, excel-addins

I'm trying to use the gnuplot add-in for Excel, but I'm having some difficulties in using it.

You can find [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot-add-in-for-excel/files/). I installed correctly but when I try to make some plot, a pop-up comes out with following message: "Single shape not selected".

I can't figure out what it means and I can't find any guide on the net.

Anyone in the community has some document\guide\tutorial on how to use it?

Comment: Not meaning to discourage you, but that add-in seems to be abandoned: the last update is almost 4 years ago. There might be people around who are still using it, but I think your are better off exporting your tables to simple TSV or CSV files and using gnuplot directly.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I do need to say though, this isn't really a programming question. See [help/on-topic]. Suggest deleting this and posting here: [Super user](https://superuser.com).